# NGINX + Letsencrypt + node.js configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, nginx-location

I'm trying to convert my site to use https. I'm running a Digital ocean VPS droplet running ubuntu 14.04.

My site is currently stored in /root.
The working NGINX reverse-proxy http server block that successfully served my site is bellow:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions from a digital ocean tutorial that uses LetsEncrypt to switch to https: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

**HTTPS works with this current NGINX server block --HOWEVER-- it appears to only serve the default nginx index.html welcome page found in /usr/share/nginx/html rather than serving my site.**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location ~ /.well-know {
        allow all;
    }   
}
```

what could be causing this??

Comment: Your should move the `location / {...}` block to `server{ listen 443......}` block. It even doesn't make any sense to have it in `server { listen 80...}` since you are redirecting to the other one with the line `return 301...`

Comment: Your SSL server isn't forwarding any requests to Node.

Comment: How might I get ssl to forward requests to Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED!

I created a /var/www directory and moved my site folder to that location.
I also changed the permissions of the directory:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/
```

My working server block now looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/path/to/site/html;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/path/to/site/html;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location ~ /.well-know {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Note: the proxy location block is important within the ssl server and required for node client-server communication.

Comment: There is a detailed article which might help others with similar issue https://www.attosol.com/implementing-ssl-free-quick/

Answer (score 0):

Write your redirect from port 80 as below by replacing $host with your site name:

`return 301 https://<your_site_name e.g. 'www.example.com'>$request_uri;`

Also, I agree with the comment of @Molda, you can remove location block from port 80 listener.

Comment: I removed the proxy location block from the first server block and replaced $host with my sitename, but it continues to load the NGINX welcome page. Any other trouble shooting I can do?